# Why can't we use dispatch_sync when doing asynchronous network testing for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I understand why `dispatch_sync` would be an issue when dispatched from the main thread when dealing with UI handling, but why is it an issue when running simple XCTests? Why can't the main thread be blocked during these tests? Why do we use semaphores rather than just synchronously dispatching these network events for testing?

Thank you.

Comment: Well assuming you're using an asynchronous method to do your network calls, you can't just wrap an asynchronous call in a `dispatch_sync` and have that block the main thread until the call comes back.  If you are doing your networking using synchronous methods that you are calling off the main thread, then you shouldn't have any issues running them on the main thread for your tests.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why in theory can't we dispatch synchronously an asynchronous call to another thread? I know it doesn't seem very intuitive, but you can't do that at all? Sorry, I'm new to multithreading.

Comment: `dispatch_sync` only blocks until the method call returns.  Asynchronous methods return immediately after enqueueing/sending their request or whatever they want to do.  It wouldn't block the thread waiting for the result of the network request to come back.

Comment: Right! That makes sense! So there is no way to call an async method in a synchronous fashion? almost like how we cast variables to different types, we can't "cast" an async method as synchronous?

Comment: Semaphores are the proper way to make an asynchronous call synchronous.

Comment: @dan do you know any easy sample code out there?

Comment: @Ricardo I suggest Ray Wenderlich's site - if you Google "grand central dispatch swift tutorial" he covers semaphores in part 2.